# WH=V matrix decomposition that allows negative values

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I'm looking for a matrix factorization method that is able to decompose a matrix:

```
V => W * H
```

- `V` has dimensions `m*n`
- `W` has dimensions `m*k`
- `H` has dimensions `k*n`
- `V`, `W`, and `H` can have negative values.
- comes with an implementation in either R, Python, or C/++

I.e., something like [Non-negative matrix factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) that allows negative values.

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Have you considered [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)? If $\Sigma$ has $k$ or fewer non-zero singular values, you can compute a $W$ and $H$ direct from the SVD, such as $W=U\Sigma^\frac{1}{2}$ and $H=\Sigma^\frac{1}{2}V^*$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I thought that one possible answer would be some variant of SVD. Unfortunately my linear algebra is so rusty that I didn't see it myself - if you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider a singular value decomposition.

If $\Sigma$ has $k$ or fewer non-zero singular values, you can compute a $W$ and $H$ direct from the SVD, such as $W=U\Sigma^\frac{1}{2}$ and $H=\Sigma^\frac{1}{2}V^∗$.

With the diagonal of $\Sigma$ ordered such that the zeroes are all at the later diagonals, columns of $W$ after the $k$-th will be all-zero (and similarly columns of $H$) and can be dropped without changing the product.